# Unable to mount SAMSUNG_Android on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

When I enable *USB debugging* in an Android phone and connect it to Ubuntu, I get a popup like:

> Unable to mount SAMSUNG_Android 
> Error initializing camera: -60: Could not lock the device

How can I disable or ignore the popup?

In Windows it works fine; the problem is just in Ubuntu.

Comment: [Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31324414/3094153)

Answer (score 54):

The problem is that Ubuntu is yet to support [MTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol) natively. I hope with the next version, [Ubuntu 13.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_13.04_.28Raring_Ringtail.29) (Raring Ringtail), they will fix this annoying problem. In the meantime, you can manually add MTP support to your Ubuntu installation's [PPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu#Package_Archives) and have seamless access to your Android device.

In *Terminal*, issue:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:langdalepl/gvfs-mtp
sudo apt-get update
```

then

```
sudo apt-get install gvfs
```

Restart your computer. You might have to turn on USB Debugging on your Android devices.

Next time when you plug it in, there shouldn't be any annoying error popups. It should appear in [Nautilus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Files) as a single device with the SD card and internal memory as sub folders, not as two mounted devices.

Data transfer should work, but you might have a problem accessing the device from some applications, in which case you might want to give [Go-mtpfs](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/12/how-to-mount-android-40-ubuntu-go-mtpfs.html) a try. It requires manual mounting/unmounting the device, (which is done in two clicks) but then everything should be as fast and easy as accessing a normal folder.

It works for me. [Ubuntu 12.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_12.04_LTS_.28Precise_Pangolin.29) (Precise Pangolin), [Samsung Galaxy S III](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S_III) and [Nexus 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nexus_7_%282012_version%29).

Comment: I'm also using SGS4.  This worked perfectly for me on Ubuntu 12.04 as well.

Comment: Works with SGS3 Android 4.1.2 on Linux Mint Release 14 (nadia).

Comment: When I followed this installation suggestion I was told that it _is_ an integral part of Ubuntu 13.10. So this suggestion is for pre-13.10 (which is what I have).

Comment: Does not work on ubuntu 13.10 with SGS 4 android 4.3 :(

Comment: I did not put my phone in debug mode and it still works. After rebooting, my phone is automatically detected and is shown next to my DVD rom. Nice!

Comment: Worked for my Samsung Note

Comment: If anyone is wondering. gvfs is included by default in Ubuntu 14.04 So if you are having this issue, it has to be something else, you can always try updating it though.

Answer (score 20):

On [Ubuntu 14.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_.28Trusty_Tahr.29) LTS (Trusty Tahr) I just had to issue:

```
sudo apt-get install mtpfs
```

It worked like magic—it didn't even need to unplug my phone.

Comment: With Ubuntu 16.04, this is what it took to connect to a Samsung Galaxy S5 mini. The udev rules file (see @Sven's answer) already contained the correct vendor and device ids.

Comment: Ubuntu 17.10 ... E: Unable to locate package mtpfs

Comment: Ubuntu 18.4 .. same as 17.10 comment

Comment: Try getting one from ppa. See if [MTPFS on Ubuntu 17.04](https://www.linuxhelp.com/how-to-install-mtpfs-on-ubuntu-17-04) helps. Cannot test it because I do not own any Samsung devices anymore. Send a note if this works.

Answer (score 15):

Today I solved the problem, with an [Wiko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiko) [DARKMOON](https://world.wikomobile.com/m106-darkmoon). The problem of Linux' the gvfs-solution was, that there was no mapping for my device in file "/lib/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules"

Attention: It could be, that you need to enable the "USB debugging", to see the device by [lsusb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lspci#lsusb). This can be done like this:

- Android 2.3 ([Gingerbread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Gingerbread)): *Settings* → *Applications* → *Development* → *USB Debugging*
- Android 4.0 ([Ice Cream Sandwich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Ice_Cream_Sandwich)): *Settings* → *Developer Options* → *USB Debugging*
- Android 4.1 ([Jelly Bean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history#Android_4.1_Jelly_Bean)): *Settings* → *Developer Options* → *USB Debugging*
- Android 4.2 or higher - Jelly Bean:

  - *Settings* → *About*
  - scroll to *Build number* and tap it 7 times
  - now you will find "Developer Options" in the "Settings"-menu
  - go to it and enable "USB Debugging"

The next steps helped me to automount my device on [Linux Mint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint) with an already-installed "gfvs":

1. Find the *vendorid* and *productid* with *lsusb*:

   ```
   lsusb

   Bus 001 Device 013: ID 0bb4:0c02 HTC (High Tech Computer Corp.) Dream / ADP1 / G1 / Magic / Tattoo (Debug)
   ...
   ```

   the "0bb4" is the vendor-id, the "0c02"is the productid
2. open the file "/lib/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules" for edit:

   ```
   gksudo gedit /lib/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules
   ```
3. Insert the new device, by duplicating a previous one and correcting the id's and save the file:

   ```
   # Wiko DARKMOON
   ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", ATTR{idProduct}=="0c02", SYMLINK+="libmtp-%k", MODE="660", GROUP="audio", ENV{ID_MTP_DEVICE}="1", ENV{ID_MEDIA_PLAYER}="1"
   ```
4. Unplug your smartphone and replug it. Your Linux should mount your device like it would do for other ones.